# Django inherited template javascript is not working

Tags: django, inheritance

I have a base template called 'baseUI.html'. I have loaded my static files using {% load static%}
.when i inherited to another template the javascript and css seems broken.
The console shows `Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Ticket/static/dashboard/script.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

but the first rendering is working perfectly but when i rout it to another the directory changes instead calling /dashboard/style.css

path('Ticket/<str:id>',RaiseTickets,name='raiseticket'),

the django server console shows `"GET /User_Management/vyshnav/static/dashboard/ajax.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3118`

why the route path is including
the code has given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load static %}
{%block content%}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Boxicons -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.9/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!-- My CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'dashboard/style.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'dashboard/script.js' %}"></script>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    
    

    

    <!-- SIDEBAR -->
    <section id="sidebar">
        <a href="#" class="brand">
            <i class='bx bxs-institution'></i>
            <span class="text">{{LoggedUser.First_Name}} {{ LoggedUser.Last_Name}}</span>
        </a>
        
        <ul class="side-menu top">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="{% url 'home' id=LoggedUser.User_Id %}">
                
                    <i class='bx bxs-home'></i>
                    <span class="text">Dashboard</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
            
                <a href="{% url 'User_Management' id=LoggedUser.User_Id %}">
                    <i class='bx bxs-user'></i>
                    <span class="text">User Management</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'raiseticket' id=LoggedUser.User_Id %}">
                    <i class='bx bxs-wallet'></i>
                    <span class="text">Tickets</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class='bx bxs-message-dots' ></i>
                    <span class="text">Chats</span>
                </a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class='bx bxs-cog' ></i>
                    <span class="text">Settings</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="logout">
                    <i class='bx bxs-log-out-circle' ></i>
                    <span class="text">Logout</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- SIDEBAR -->



    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <section id="content">
        <!-- NAVBAR -->
        <nav>
            <i class='bx bx-menu' ></i>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Categories</a>
            <form action="#">
                <div class="form-input">
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
                    <button type="submit" class="search-btn"><i class='bx bx-search' ></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <input type="checkbox" id="switch-mode" hidden>
            <label for="switch-mode" class="switch-mode"></label>
            <a href="#" class="notification">
                <i class='bx bxs-bell' ></i>
                <span class="num">0</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="profile">
                <i class='bx bxs-user-circle'></i>
            </a>
        </nav>
        <!-- NAVBAR -->

        <!-- MAIN -->
        <main>
            <div class="head-title">
                <div class="left">
                    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
                    <ul class="breadcrumb">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><i class='bx bx-chevron-right' ></i></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
<!-- AJAX implementing -->
{%block body%}
            

            
{% endblock %} 



        </main>
        <!-- MAIN -->
    </section>
    <!-- CONTENT -->
    
    

    <script src="static/dashboard/script.js"></script>
    <script src="static/dashboard/ajax.js"></script>


</body>
{%endblock%}
</html>
```

and the inherited child template is

```
{% extends "baseUI.html" %}

{% block body %}
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {%csrf_token%}
{{ form.as_p}}
{{form2.as_p}}

</form>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value={{LoggedUser.User_Id}}>Submit</button>
{%endblock%}
```

#### Tried out everything as of my knowledgeline

Comment: please post path, view and html template for User_Management

Answer (score 0):

please change at the bottom of html file

```
   <script src="static/dashboard/script.js"></script>
   <script src="static/dashboard/ajax.js"></script>
```

to

```
   <script src="{% static '/dashboard/script.js' %}"></script>
   <script src="{% static '/dashboard/ajax.js' %}"></script>
```

remark: you have several points in your question - this does not solve all.

Comment: Thanks for your support! I think the problem in my code was "I declared the script tag at the top , So in my assumption the imported JavaScript code should be  declared at the bottom ".When I changed it top to bottom it's working fine.